# C++ Syntax Error

Tags: c++, function

I'm getting this error:

```
prog.cpp:1:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
```

Form this code:

```
int [] quick_srt(int array[], int low, int n){
```

That's the problem, please?

**EDIT**

```
int [] quick_srt(int array[], int low, int n){
int lo = low;
int hi = n;
comp++;
if (lo >= n){ // lo is greater then or equal to n
    return array;
}
int mid = array[(lo + hi) / 2];  //Using mid as pivot
comp++;
while (lo < hi){ //lo is less then hi

    comp++;
    while (lo < hi && array[lo] < mid){ //lo less than hi AND array[lo] less than mid
        lo++;
        comp++;
    }

    comp++;
    while (lo < hi && array[hi] > mid) {//lo less than hi AND array[lo] greater than mid
        hi--;
        comp++;
    }

    comp++; //for if
    comp++; //for else
    if(array[lo] == array[hi]){
    break; //for duplicate items
    }
    else if (lo < hi) { // less than
        int T = array[lo];
        array[lo] = array[hi];
        array[hi] = T;
        swaps++;
    }
    comp++;
}
comp++;
if (hi < lo) { //hi is less than lo
    int T = hi;
    hi = lo;
    lo = T;
}
quick_srt(array, low, lo); //recrusie call
quick_srt(array, lo == low ? lo+1 : lo, n); //re-call, if lo = low, increment lo else pass lo and n
return array;
  }
```

Comment: `int []` isn't valid C++.

Comment: @dauphic, It is when used as a parameter, however.

Comment: Use `std::array`. You'll be a lot happier.

Comment: @chris: Yes, but it declares a parameter of pointer type -- and if the parameter has a name, that goes between the `int` and the `[]` (`int param[]`, not `int[] param`).

Comment: @KeithThompson, Precisely, but to say outright that `int[]` isn't valid C++ is technically wrong. It's just pedantry.

Comment: Why aren't you using `void` as your return type? That function doesn't need to return anything as it just modifies the data pointed to by `array`.

Comment: @NikosC. It's just a function, I'm passing it out so I can print it.

Comment: The caller passes in a pointer to the first element of an array. The function modifies that array. The caller can call the function and then print the modified array. There's no need for the function to return a value.

Comment: @AdegokeA You need to learn about pointers and arrays. Arrays in C++ work very differently from how you think they do. I guess you are used to C# or Java but you can't just assume that C++ is the same. You aren't going to get very far with this kind of program until you get a better understanding of how arrays and pointers really work. Get a book, all this will be explained better than anyone can here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return an array from a function.  the `int array[]` in the parameter list is just syntactic sugar for `int *array`, and there's no analogue for the return value.  If you want to return a pointer, you'll need to do so explicitly:

```
int *quick_srt(int array[], int low, int n);
```

or, equivalently:

```
int *quick_srt(int *array, int low, int n);
```

Comment: And if you could, that probably wouldn't be the syntax for it. `int[]` looks more like C#.

Comment: The return type looks useless anyway. Could just be `void`.

Comment: But I initialised an array like this `int array[size];`. How do I convert `[]array` to `*array`?

Comment: I don't know what `[]array` is supposed to mean, but an array decays into a pointer to its first element in most contexts.

Comment: int array[10]; int *p; p = array; p[6] = 1; -> array[6] == 1 TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

`int []` is only valid for function arguments. I'd suggest you do this instead:

```
void quick_srt(std::vector<int>& array, int low)
```

You don't need the `n` argument. USe `array.size() instead.

Comment: Also note the `sort` function in `<algorithm>`

Answer (score 0):

One more way is use 
void quick_srt(int * array, int low)

I would suggest go with vector its lot more easy